# Write dynamically allocated structure to file

Tags: c, io, structure

Suppose we have following structure:

```
    struct Something {
        int i;
    };
```

If I want to write in a file any data of this type(dynamically allocated), I do this:

```
struct Something *object = malloc(sizeof(struct Something));
object->i = 0; // set member some value
FILE *file = fopen("output_file", "wb");
fwrite(object, sizeof(struct Something), 1 file);
fclose(file);
```

Now, my questions:

How we do this with a structure what contains pointers? I tested using same method, it worked fine, data could been read, but I want to know if there are any risks?

Comment: the pointers are only relevant during THIS particular instance of the program. if you write a pointer out to a file, then read it back into some other process later on, it'll be just a random number and cause major problems - the new instance's memory layout/usage will be completely different.

Comment: If you are talking about structures like Linked Lists, then write the data in order without pointers. When reading, you will need to recreate the List with pointer allocations after reading the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). See also [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) (a portable binary data format) & [libs11n](http://s11n.net/s11n/) (a C++ binary serialization library); you often care about data portability: being able to read the data on some *different* computer.

"serialization" means to "convert" some complex data structure (e.g. a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29), a vector or even your `Something`...) into a (serial) byte stream (e.g. a file, a network connection, etc...), and backwards. Dealing with circular data structures or shared sub-components may be tricky.

You don't want to write raw pointers inside a file (but you could), because the written address probably won't make any sense at the next execution of your program (e.g. because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)), i.e. when you'll read the data again.

Read also about [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing) and [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29).

For pragmatic reasons (notably ease of debugging and resilience w.r.t. small software evolution) it is often better to use some [textual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol) data format (like e.g. [JSON](http://json.org/) or [Yaml](http://yaml.org/)) to store such persistent data.

You might also be interested in [databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database). Look first into [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), and also into DBMS ("relational" -or [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) based- ones like [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/), [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) ones like e.g. [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org/))

The issue is not writing a single dynamically allocated `struct` (since you want mostly to write the data content, not the pointer, so it is the same to `fwrite`  a `malloc`-ed `struct` or a locally allocated one), it is to serialize complex data structures which use lots of weird internal pointers!

Notice that copying [garbage collectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) use algorithms similar to serialization algorithms (since both need to scan a complex [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29) of references).

Also, on today's computers, disk -or network- IO is a lot  (e.g. a million times) slower than the CPU, so it makes sense to do some significant computation before writing files.