# C Socket/Client fork(), share struct memory

Tags: c, sockets, struct, fork, shared-memory

I'm trying to share the memory of a struct on my C server, got the following code

```
// Before the main
struct Esami {
    char nome[20];
    char cognome[20];
    char matricola[20];
    char voto[20];
};

struct Appelli {
    int stato;
    char dipartimento[20];
    char cdl[20];
    char nomeEsame[20];
    char data[20];
    struct Esami esame[10];
    int numEsamiRegistrati;
} *appello[100];
```

This is what I do in my fork:

```
// After creating socket, bind(), listen() and so on..
if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
    shmid = shmget(2009, sizeof(appello), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    *appello = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
    close (listenfd); // Closes the parent socket
    // Operations on this struct (like the one I explained below)
    exit(0);
}
```

I try to access the fields of the struct by using the arrow operator, however the program probably gets a memory error so if I populate a field and try for example

```
printf("Dipartimento: %s", appello[0]-> dipartimento);
```

The server program crashes: every other input from the clients doesn't get read anymore. I managed to get it working with a single struct variable (like *appello) but once I start using arrays (*appello[100]) I get this problem.

The question is: how can I share the memory segment of this array of struct to every client connecting to the server?

Please note that I'm trying to understand a university exercise and I have to solve it with shared memory and fork.

Comment: Why don't you [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) your data structure on the socket? See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28373401/841108) to a related question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***First*** just a comment on your example:

```
`printf("Dipartimento: %s", appello[0]-> dipartimento);`    
 this space does not belong in any form ^
```

***Note:***, for the comments below, I did not have the definition of your struct member `struct Esami esame[10];`, so had to simplify representations of your struct in all illustrations.

***Next point***, For illustration of a different method, change:

```
struct Appelli {
    int stato;
    ....
    int numEsamiRegistrati;
} *appello[100];
```

***To***:

```
typedef struct {
    int stato;
    ....
    int numEsamiRegistrati;
} APPELLO;
APPELLO appello[100], *pAppello;
```

***In main()*** (or in any executable section of your code) perform this initialization:

```
pAppello, = &appello[0];//initializes your pointer to a copy of struct  
pAppello = malloc(sizeof(APPELLO));
```

***Then, when using*** the *pointer*, reference members like this:

```
pAppello->cdl;//use -> for pointer
```

***When using*** the *array*, reference members like this:

```
appello[0].cdl;//use . for non-pointer
```

If you want an ***array of pointers***, then initialize differently:

```
pAppello = &appello[0];//initializes your pointer to a copy of struct  
pAppello = malloc(sizeof(APPELLO)*100); //provides 100 instances of pAppello
```

Now, you have an array of pointers to the struct, and you will again 
use `.` to access its members:

```
pAppello[0].cdl;
```

For additional reading here is a good ***[tutorial on C structures](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm)*** .

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, I updated my question with the struct "Esame" but from your code I still don't understand if I assigned the memory segment properly in order to share that struct between all the forked processes

Comment: @wiredmark - Have you read, and understood the content on this ***[page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat)***?  This is key: _A successful shmat() call updates the members of the shmid_ds structure_.  This structure is already defined, but you have created your own.

Comment: ***Regarding your memory question*** - I am not sure I understand, but I'll take a shot: By creating an array of pointers to `APPELLO`, you should be able to use each instance to store information for each process you create.  In the example, we created an array of 100, so you should be able to store information for up to 100 different processes. `pAppello[0].cdl;` for first process, `pAppello[1].cdl;` for the second process, all the way through `pAppello[99].cdl;` for the 100th process.